# Updated Record Not Showing Up in a Table After a Trigger Update

Tags: postgresql

I created a table, `payment_detail`, based on two other tables (customer and payment) as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS payment_detail AS
SELECT customer.customer_id,
   customer.first_name || ' ' || customer.last_name AS customer_name,
   to_char(payment_date, 'Mon YYYY') AS month_yr,
   SUM(payment.amount) AS total_amount,
   COUNT(payment.amount) AS payments_count
FROM payment
INNER JOIN customer ON payment.customer_id = customer.customer_id
GROUP BY 1,3
ORDER BY
   MAX(date_trunc('year', payment_date)) DESC,
   MAX(date_trunc('month', payment_date)) DESC,
   MAX(amount) DESC;
```

Goal: Create a trigger function to update the `payment_detail` table upon an UPDATE and an INSERT operation.

Trigger for the UPDATE operation:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_payment_detail()
   RETURNS TRIGGER LANGUAGE PLPGSQL AS
$$
BEGIN
   UPDATE payment_detail SET
   customer_id = NEW.customer_id,
   customer_name = first_name || ' ' || last_name,
   month_yr = to_char(NEW.payment_date, 'Mon YYYY'),
FROM
   customer
WHERE
   customer.customer_id = NEW.customer_id AND
   payment_detail.customer_id = OLD.customer_id;
RETURN NULL;
END;
$$

CREATE TRIGGER update_payment_detail
   AFTER UPDATE
   ON payment
   FOR EACH ROW
   EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_payment_detail();
```

The problem with the above Trigger is that, although it updates the payment table successfully, **the updated record no longer shows up in the `payment_detail` table.**
For instance, if I perform an UPDATE as follows:

```
UPDATE payment
SET amount = 9.00
WHERE customer_id = 60 AND payment_id = 32034;
```

The `payment_detail` table no longer shows the record for 'Mildred Bailey' as pictured above, in the first row of the table. But if I `DROP TABLE payment_detail;` and re-run the table creation, then the record appears.

How would I prevent this from happening? I think the answer is rooted in the condition of my `WHERE` clause, but I could use some guidance on this if that's the case.

Next, is the trigger for the INSERT operation:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_payment_detail()
   RETURNS TRIGGER LANGUAGE PLPGSQL AS
$$
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO payment_detail (customer_id, month_yr, total_amount, payments_count)
   SELECT
      NEW.customer_id,
      to_char(NEW.payment_date, 'Mon YYYY') AS month_yr,
      SUM(NEW.amount) AS total_amount,
      COUNT(NEW.amount) AS payments_count
   FROM customer, payment
   WHERE customer.customer_id = NEW.customer_id AND
   to_chair(payment.payment_date, 'Mon YYYY') = to_char(NEW.payment_date, 'Mon YYYY');
RETURN NULL;
END;
$$

CREATE TRIGGER insert_payment_detail
   AFTER INSERT ON payment
   FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE insert_payment_detail();
```

If I apply an INSERT as follows:

```
INSERT INTO payment (customer_id staff_id, rental_id, amount, payment_date)
VALUES (60, 2, 14741, 4.00, now());
```

I verify that the payment table holds the new record; however when I run `SELECT * FROM payment_detail`, it does not show the new record. So in both my UPDATE and INSERT trigger functions, the targeted table just omits the updated/inserted record, until I delete and recreate the table.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Question/notes 1) In `UPDATE` function why use `OLD.customer_id` and `NEW.customer_id`, are they going to be different? 2) When doing the `SELECT` after the `UPDATE` the record will probably not show in first row. SQL is not ordered by default, so you have to use `ORDER BY`. Do you find the record  if you select for customer_id=60? 3) Your `INSERT` trigger function has `to_chair(payment.payment_date ...`' which I believe is supposed to be `to_char(...`. That would throw an error and keep the function from running. Add answers as update to your question.

Comment: FYI, this could probably be handled with a [View](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createview.html).

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I see that I had a misconception about what the NEW keyword actually did, which Edouard points out in his answer below. So to answer your question, the customer_id would NOT be updated; only the customer's name, and any of their payment details in the payment table (e.g. date, amount, etc.) would really be updated.

The big insight from your answer, which in hindsight seems so blatantly obvious, is that I should not have used the SELECT * FROM ... without an ORDER BY to test the updates/inserts. Thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Trigger(s) for UPDATE**

(a) You may have an error in your trigger function `update_payment_detail()`, try to replace

```
customer_name = first_name || ' ' || last_name
```

by

```
customer_name = NEW.first_name || ' ' || NEW.last_name
```

(b) The columns of the table `payment_detail` are copied from both tables `customer` and `payment`, so you probably need 2 different trigger functions for update :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_payment_detail()
   RETURNS TRIGGER LANGUAGE PLPGSQL AS
$$
BEGIN
   UPDATE payment_detail SET
--   customer_id = NEW.customer_id, -- NEW.customer_id is not possible here if it is a column of the table customer; NEW only refers to the columns of the table payment called by the trigger !
--   customer_name = NEW.first_name || ' ' || NEW.last_name, -- idem as above if these columns come from the table customer
   month_yr = to_char(NEW.payment_date, 'Mon YYYY')
--FROM
--   customer
WHERE
--   customer.customer_id = NEW.customer_id AND
   payment_detail.customer_id = OLD.customer_id ;
RETURN NULL;
END;
$$

CREATE TRIGGER update_payment_detail
   AFTER UPDATE
   ON payment
   FOR EACH ROW
   EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_payment_detail();

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_customer_detail()
   RETURNS TRIGGER LANGUAGE PLPGSQL AS
$$
BEGIN
   UPDATE payment_detail SET
   customer_id = NEW.customer_id,
   customer_name = NEW.first_name || ' ' || NEW.last_name
--   month_yr = to_char(NEW.payment_date, 'Mon YYYY') -- NEW.payment_date is not possible here if it is a column of the table payment; NEW only refers to the columns of the table customer called by the trigger !
--FROM
--   customer
WHERE
   customer.customer_id = OLD.customer_id
--   payment_detail.customer_id = OLD.customer_id ;
RETURN NULL;
END;
$$

CREATE TRIGGER update_customer_detail
   AFTER UPDATE
   ON customer
   FOR EACH ROW
   EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_customer_detail();
```

**Trigger for INSERT**

(c) The reference to the table `customer` sounds like useless in this trigger function. You can try this :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_payment_detail()
   RETURNS TRIGGER LANGUAGE PLPGSQL AS
$$
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO payment_detail (customer_id, month_yr, total_amount, payments_count)
   SELECT
      NEW.customer_id,
      to_char(NEW.payment_date, 'Mon YYYY'),
      SUM(amount),
      COUNT(*)
   FROM payment
   WHERE customer_id = NEW.customer_id AND
   to_char(payment_date, 'Mon YYYY') = to_char(NEW.payment_date, 'Mon YYYY');
RETURN NULL;
END;
$$

CREATE TRIGGER insert_payment_detail
   AFTER INSERT ON payment
   FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE insert_payment_detail();
```

(d) Depending on the primary key of the table `payment_detail`, it is possible that you may have some conflicts when inserting 2 rows in table `payment` with the same `customer_id` and the same `to_char(payment_date, 'Mon YYYY')` value. In order to prevent any conflict, you can add the clause `ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE ...`

(e) Finally, the table `payment_detail` could be replaced by a ***view*** as proposed by @Adrian Klaver